# Infinitude of the set of "Lucky Numbers"

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Was recently working with the ["Lucky Numbers"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number) and their properties.  How would one go about proving that they are infinite?

I've figure the proof will somehow involve assuming that the set is finite and coming up with some way to generate another lucky out of that finite set, but I'm at a loss as to how to actually perform this, since the sieving process  used to generate this set isn't easily manipulatable (at least to me)

Comment: You could improve this question by explaining what "Lucky Numbers" are. Posting the Wikipedia link as an additional reference would have been a good idea, but not as the sole source of the definition. Why should I have to follow links to other sites just to understand your questions?!

Comment: Every step in the construction of the list increases the number of final elements by one. So say you want to know that there are more than $100,000$ of them. Do $100,000$ deletions, and the first $100,000$ numbers in your list will be lucky. Since this works for any natural number, the final list of lucky numbers cannot be finite.

Answer (score 1):

Just consider how lucky numbers are generated :

1. At first $S_0=\{2n+1\;|\;n\in\mathbb N\}$, and $L_0=\{1\}\subset S_0$
2. When you have $L_n\subset S_n$, with $L_n$ finite and $S_n$ infinite, consider the minimum $m_n$ of $S_n\setminus L_n$ (this is an infinite set of integers, so it have a minimum). Then $m_n$ is a lucky number and consider $L_{n+1}=L_n\cup\{m_n\}$, and $S_{n+1}$ is obtained from $S_n$ by removing all $k.m_n^\mbox{th}$ elements of $S_{n}$. So $S_{n+1}$ is still infinite. So you can repeat this process of all $n$, and there is an infinite number of lucky numbers $m_n$.

Comment: Xoff, thank you. In purely verbal terms, is what you're saying that after each sieving process, the minimum number in the set (that hasn't already been the minimum after a past sieve) is a lucky, and that since the set to be sieved is infinite, an infinite number of sieves can be performed, and by this method of "lucky acknowledgement" we will always be able to identify a *new* lucky after each sieve?